# Read bytes io using spark rdd (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `Spark 3` and have a zip file which comprises multi csv files with same file format.

I do not wanna localize the csv files to dbfs/hdfs and read them again because that may cause extra time. The file may very large so I don't wanna `pandas read_csv` as well.

It seems the `spark.read.format("csv").xxx` only supports files not bytes io, so I tried to use `spark rdd` to deal with this case.

```
 sc = spark.sparkContext

 with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as z:
        # read files in the zip one by one
        for filename in z.namelist():
            # filter out directories
            if not filename.endswith('/'):
                # read file
                with z.open(filename) as f: 
                    bytes_io = BytesIO(f.read())
                    tmp_file=bytes_io.getvalue().decode("utf-8") 
                    print(tmp_file)
                    rdd = sc.parallelize(tmp_file)
                    print(11111)
                    parsed_rdd = rdd.map(parse_csv) 
                    print(f"2222222:::::{parsed_rdd}")
```

The script can show the variable `tmp_file` as expected but then it stops without any error: `11111` is not shown and following codes are not executed.

Why could this happen and is there any other way to do this?